# How to drag a copy of an Item through Drag and DropArea mechanism in QML?

Tags: qt, drag-and-drop, qml

**Hello**,
I'm using Qt 5.2.1 for Android on windows

I've gone through the different drag and drop examples provided with Qt, but non of them address my problem, although I found [This Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtquick-externaldraganddrop-example.html) copy Text via drag and drop, but I want to copy a whole Item.

**Note**: I don't want external copy, just inside the application.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 0):

Am a noop, this is just an idea,

1. Create a new Object ( same as your dragged Item )
2. Copy the Dragged item properties into the newly created object
3. Destroy the source

lets say you have and Item:

```
    // DraggedItem.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
    id:draggedItem
    property string itemText
    property string imageSource
    Image {
        id: img
        source: imageSource
    }
    Text {
        id: txt
        text: qsTr("text")
    }
}
```

Then you can have your drop area like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
Item {
id:dropItem

DropArea {
    id: dropArea
    anchors.fill: parent

    onDropped: {
        if (drop.source.parent !== draggedItem) {

            // Create new Item
            var newItem = createNewItem();

            // Copy the source item properties into the new one
            newItem.width = parent.width;
            newItem.height = drop.source.height;
            newItem.itemText = drop.source.itemText
            newItem.imageSource = drop.source.imageSource

            // destroy the source
            drop.source.destroy();
        }

    }

}

function createNewItem() {
    var component = Qt.createComponent("DraggedItem.qml");
    if (component.status === Component.Ready)
    {
        var newItem = component.createObject(parent, {"x":0,
                                                 "y":0});
        if (newItem === null)
            console.log("Error creating new Item");

    }
    return newItem
  } 
}
```

**This code is not tested. There should be a better way to do this**

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here.  You create a duplicate of the source object, then destroy it, so you still only have one dragged object despite the OP asking for a copy.  This behaviour is no different to the normal QML drag, only it's tons more code.